# How to paste text from clipboard with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, phonegap-plugins

I want paste text from clipboard with phonegap but when I searched in stackoverflow I could not found any perfect way.did you show me example or solution???

Comment: dont you think your question is a little unclear and hard to understand?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you can use jQuery Mobile to do this. But I found this [CordovaClipboard](https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard) plugin that allows you to access the clipboard and gives you the ability to paste and copy text.